# Latest tweet not always showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

With the follow code, the latest tweet is only occasionally showing in Chrome but always in Firefox. Typically only shows in Chrome with /? on the url but vanishes when I refresh.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
console.log("getting twitter data..");
jQuery.getJSON("http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/*hidden*.json?callback=?", function(data) {
    console.log("got it..", data);
        jQuery("#tweet").html(data[0].text);
        jQuery("#ttime").html(data[0].created_at);
} );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the direct JSON from the twitter API. This is not possible due the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You are only allowed to get JSON from your own domain.

A workaround exists and it's called JSONP (JSON with padding) and that's what twitter is using. You need to append the name of a function to the `callback` parameter in the URL. This function then gets executed when the twitter API loads.

For example you could do it like this:

**JavaScript**

```
function render(data) {
  // data is the object that contains your twitter data. It's an usual JavaScript object.
}
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username?
callback=render"></script>
```

Make sure that `render` is already loaded when the twitter API loads.